# Use Web.config instead of app.config for integration test in ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, testing

I have a web app which contains a project called EnterpriseInfrastructure with a class called Pager. This class simply creates a PagerClient specified by a WSDL which is linked in a service reference.

When I run the application in production, the PagerClient is initialized with settings from the Web.config from the application. That works great. But when I try to perform an integration test to make sure we have the correct endpoints specified in the Web.config, an exception is thrown that the configuration file is not found. The service is looking for the app.config--not the web.config.

Is there a way to run the test in the same way as our web app, so that the web.config is called upon rather than the app.config?

I am using `[DeploymentItem(@"../../../UI/Web.config")]` to copy the web.config from our actual project.

Answer (score 0):

Your unit test project also needs the web.config in order to run the test.  I have typically done this with other app.config files by doing Add Existing Item, navigate to the web.config in the other project, and then press the little down arrow on the `Add` button and choose `Add as Link`

This way any changes you make in the main config file will also be used by the test project... you won't need to manage two config files.

EDIT: This appears to only work with app.config files, I couldn't get my test project to ignore the app.config and use a linked web.config